# Dynamically created class with invocant constraint

Tags: raku, rakudo

Official [docs](https://rakudocs.github.io/language/mop) says that class can be built dynamically like so:

```
constant A := Metamodel::ClassHOW.new_type( name => 'A' );
A.^add_method('x', my method x(A:D:) { say 42 });
A.^compose;                                                 
     
A.new.x(); # x will be only called on instances
```

But what if I am building a class and don't assign it to a constant but rather store it in a var (for instance when I need to create a bunch of classes in loop) like so:

```perl
my $x = Metamodel::ClassHOW.new_type( name => 'some custom string' );
$x.^add_method('x', my method ($y:) { say $y });
$x.^compose;
```

But in this case I can call method `x` both on class (`$x.x`) and on instance (`$x.new.x`) though I want it to only be called on instances.
I tried to define method like so:

```
$x.^add_method('x', my method ($y:D:) { say $y });
```

but that produces an error:

```
Invalid typename 'D' in parameter declaration.
```

Of course I can check defindness of the value inside the method but I want some compile-time guarantees (I want to believe that type checking is done in compile time).

I tried to play with [signatures](https://rakudocs.github.io/type/Signature) and [parameters](https://rakudocs.github.io/type/Parameter) but couldn't find a way to create an invocant parameter but what is more important I am not sure how to assign signature which I have in a variable to some method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change:

```
my $x = ...
```

to:

```
my constant x = my $ = ...
```

In full:

```
my constant x = my $ = Metamodel::ClassHOW.new_type( name => 'some custom string' );
x.^add_method('x', my method (x:D $y:) { say $y });
x.^compose;
x = Metamodel::ClassHOW.new_type( name => 'another custom string' );
...
```

> I want some compile-time guarantees (I want to believe that type checking is done in compile time).

By making the `constant`'s RHS be a variable declaration, you blend static compile-time aspects with dynamic run-time ones.

(BTW, the `my` before `constant` is just me being pedantic. A plain `constant` like you've used is equivalent to `our constant` which is less strict than `my constant`.)

I note the error message for a non-instance is different:

```
Type check failed in binding to parameter '$y';
expected type some custom string cannot be itself
```

At a guess that's because the usual message comes from `Mu` or `Any` and your class isn't inheriting from either of them.

> I am not sure how to assign signature which I have in a variable to some method.

I'll leave that part unanswered.

Comment: Is that something stupid I've asked? That's why you leave that part unanswered? :) It's the first language I've meat where the signature of the method is an object. So I thought there might be some capabilities to kinda "apply" it to a method. I tried to create a 'Method' object but Raku(do) won't allow that

Comment: Nope, not stupid at all. I've researched the signature part and given up. I hoped someone else would address it. But it was better than I hoped: jnthn answered! His answer is truly awesome, as is invariably the case whenever he has time to write answers. Moreover, it covers what I now recognize was the harder part of your question.

Answer (score 5):

The best way I can think of to produce a method with types substituted into a signature with Raku today is to use a parametric role to help out, like this:

```
my role Helper[::T] {
    method foo(T $inv:) {}
}
my &meth = Helper.^parameterize(Int).^pun.^lookup("foo");
say &meth.signature;
```

Which outputs `(Int $inv: *%_)`. Substitute `Int` with the type you are building.

Comment: .oO( Why has jnthn written `Helper.^parameterize(Int)` instead of `Helper[Int]`? Current bookie odds... 5-1: to stick to nqp subset (does it?); 4-1: to cut some bootstrapping gordian knot; 3-1: didn't think about it. )

Comment: @raiph If one has a role in a variable and some something like `$role[$param]`, that compiles as an array index, not a parameterization. While that may not be done here, given the context is generation, I provided a general form that will always work if, say, the role is dynamically selected.